# In what cases EHLO will return 4xy or 5xy?

Tags: smtp

I don't understand sense of `EHLO` or `HELO` command after a client established connection to a `SMTP` server. In what cases server will return `4XY` or `5XY` codes in response to either `EHLO` or `HELO`. I cant find anything about this cases at 4.1.1.1 of [**RFC5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).

Comment: You're looking for [error codes](http://info.webtoolhub.com/kb-a15-smtp-status-codes-smtp-error-codes-smtp-reply-codes.aspx). They're obviously implementation dependent, but they can happen for many reasons. For example 422 - User has exceeded mail limit.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch _For example 422 - User has exceeded mail limit._ I dont understand why this error may be caused? We pass a fully-qualified domain name as parameter in `HELO` or address literal. How this info about adress/domain_name may be used by server?

Comment: How about because they cannot receive an unlimited number of messages / size of message.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why we must to pass domain_name or address as parameter of `EHLO/HELO`? How it can used by server?

Comment: The server may support [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).